# PHP object iteration

Tags: php

I run the following PHP-code:

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl");

var_dump($client->checkVat(array(
  'countryCode' => 'BE',
  'vatNumber' => '0861091467'
)));

foreach ($client as $key => $value) {
   echo $key . ' = ' . $value . "\n";
}
```

It procudes the following output on screen:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (6) {
  ["countryCode"]=>
  string(2) "BE"
  ["vatNumber"]=>
  string(10) "0861091467"
  ["requestDate"]=>
  string(16) "2021-03-10+01:00"
  ["valid"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["name"]=>
  string(8) "BV myKMO"
  ["address"]=>
  string(26) "Kapellebaan 55
2560 Nijlen"
}
_soap_version = 1
sdl = Resource id #2
httpsocket = Resource id #3
_use_proxy = 0
httpurl = Resource id #4
```

Then how can we store "BV myKMO" in a one-dimensional variable ? I'm looking for something like

```
$varname = $client->sdl->name;
```

Thank you,

Comment: Your `var_dump` and `foreach` output are totally different and neither shows the `sdl` property.

Comment: `and the following loop...would produce`...not from the previous data you showed, it wouldn't. If you're going to use examples that's great, but please at least check that they make sense before posting them :-)

Comment: `echo $myvar->name;` should be what you need to in order to refer to the value. It's unclear where `sdl` comes into it. Simple demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3d8204796c12c2c997984c88c4452fb164b9f191

Comment: $client = new SoapClient("https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl");
    var_dump($client->checkVat(array(
      'countryCode' => 'BE',
      'vatNumber' => '0861091467'
    )));

Comment: Sorry but it's unclear what the relevance of that code snippet is to the rest of your question? If you have more info for us, please use the "edit" button under your question to update your original post fully with both the code you want to share, and an explanation of how it's relevant to your question. Don't assume we can read your mind or understand everything about your application without context. Also don't assume that we can execute any random code you show us. If you're talking about the output of that code, please show us the output within your question. Thanks.

Comment: Also, did you try my suggestion? Did it help?

Comment: Hi ADyson, thanks for your reply - indeed I tried your suggestion but it showed an empty result for me. I've just edited my original question above - hopefully this makes it more clear.

Comment: Your issue is that `$client` doesn't contain the data. It contains your SOAP client. Your data is contained in the object returned by the call to the `checkVat()` function...but you're only feeding that to var_dump, you aren't retaining it for later use. And I still have no idea why you think `sdl` is relevant to anything, it's unclear what's in it just from that foreach output. (why you didn't `var_dump($client)` too for your debugging instead of using foreach, I don't understand).

Comment: Try this: `$result = $client->checkVat(array(
  'countryCode' => 'BE',
  'vatNumber' => '0861091467'
)); echo $result->name;`

Comment: Yep, that does it -  ... thanks!

Comment: Great. I've posted as proper answer below for you to upvote/accept - thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `$client` doesn't contain the data. It merely contains your SOAP client - i.e. it contains functions which enable you to request data from the server, but not the data which is obtained from executing those requests.

The result data you want is contained in the object returned by the call to the `checkVat()` function...but you're only feeding that to var_dump, you aren't retaining it for later use.

Try this instead:

```
$result = $client->checkVat(array( 'countryCode' => 'BE', 'vatNumber' => '0861091467' )); 
echo $result->name;
```